# Azure function not firing after deploy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have created azure function of type Blob trigger. It runs successfully locally. But when I deployed the c# code using Visual studio publish, the trigger never fired.

Please suggest any solution.
**Even the simple trigger function created on the portal is not firing**.
I followed this video to create function.

```
[FunctionName("ImageResizeFunction")]
        public void Run(
            [BlobTrigger("normal-size/{name}")] Stream inputBlob,
            [Blob("reduced-size/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
            string name,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {inputBlob.Length} Bytes");

            try
            {
                this.imageResizer.Resize(inputBlob, outputBlob);
                log.LogInformation("Reduced image saved to blob storage");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogError("Resize fails", e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***We have also tried to create sample function app using blob trigger and it works fine in local and Azure well.***

Here are the workaround we follow;

*Created one simple Azure function in local and provide the storage account endpoint details in `localsettings.json` and provide the container name in `function.cs` file and trying to upload files on container and it works.*

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class BlobTrigger1
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTrigger1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("ajaytest/{name}", Connection = "cloudtestajaymt_STORAGE")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT IN LOCAL:-***

[image]

*Then when publish this blob trigger to Azure function we need to specify the connection string of storage account in configuration of Azure function . As on our `localsettings.json`* .

*As shown below:-*
[image]
[image]

***After set the application settings goto >Function>Monitor> And check the Invocations where you will be able to see the logs of upload files/images to the blob.***

**NOTE:-** ***This logs takes upto 5 minutes to be loaded in invocations***.

***OUTPUT LOGS FROM PORTAL:-***

[image]
[image]

For more information please refer this **Blog**|[***Deploy Azure Function - Blob Trigger From Visual Studio***](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-azure-function-blob-trigger-from-visual-studio/)

Comment: I had done implementation the way you have shown here. My code worked when I added "Azurewebjobsstorage" in function app application settings.

Comment: Thanks!!!

The key step is to copy the connection string into the Function App Config!!!!!